# What the context window size in pre-train gpt-2

Tags: language-models, pre-training, gpt

I have questions about GPT-2.

What is the context window in the pre-train gpt-2 train?
As I know language modeling is based on gpt-2 use prefix language modeling that is demonstrated in picture form T5 model below:
[image]
And the formula of gpt model indicate below :

[image]

So I would like to know what the number of K(context size)? that the initial first stage for training in pre-train GPT-2?

If GPT is not prefix language modeling, then what is it?

Comment: The answer to your question is given in the paper introducing GPT-2.